# How to test a gwt composite component with ui binder using GwtTestCase?

Tags: java, gwt, junit, uibinder, gwttestcase

I am trying to test my gwt project using GwtTestCase.
But I can't create an instance of a Composite component.

Here is the code and stack trace...

**Login.java** (My composite component)

```
public class Login extends Composite{  
    @UiField    
    TextBox userName;  

    @UiField  
    TextBox password;

    @UiField  
    Button loginButton;  

    private static LoginUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(LoginUiBinder.class);  

    interface LoginUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Login> {}      

    public Login() {  
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));  
        loginButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  

        @Override  
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.alert("clicked");            
            }
        });  
    }  
}
```

**Login.ui.xml**(ui binder xml content)

```
<g:HTMLPanel>  
    <div>  
        <g:Label text="username:"></g:Label>  
        <g:TextBox ui:field="userName"></g:TextBox>  
    </div>  
    <div>  
        <g:Label text="password:"></g:Label>  
        <g:TextBox ui:field="password"></g:TextBox>  
    </div>      
    <g:Button ui:field="loginButton" text="Login"></g:Button>  
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

**LoginTest.java** (This is my Gwt TesCase)

```
public class SampleGwtTestCase extends GWTTestCase{  
    public void test01(){  
        Login login = new Login();  
    }  

    @Override  
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "com.mycompany.TestingGwt";  
    }
}
```

**Error stack trace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Remote test failed at 192.168.2.15 / Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.processTestResult(JUnitShell.java:1283)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1403)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1304)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:652)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:441)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:296)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null) @com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplTrident::isOrHasChildImpl(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Node;Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Node;)([JavaScript object(22), JavaScript object(26)]): null
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeBoolean(ModuleSpace.java:194)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeBoolean(JavaScriptHost.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplTrident.isOrHasChildImpl(DOMImplTrident.java)
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplTrident.isOrHasChild(DOMImplTrident.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node$.isOrHasChild$(Node.java:280)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:220)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:190)
    at com.mycompany.client.login.Login_LoginUiBinderImpl$Widgets.build_f_HTMLPanel1(Login_LoginUiBinderImpl.java:95)
    at com.mycompany.client.login.Login_LoginUiBinderImpl$Widgets.get_f_HTMLPanel1(Login_LoginUiBinderImpl.java:77)
    at com.mycompany.client.login.Login_LoginUiBinderImpl$Widgets.access$0(Login_LoginUiBinderImpl.java:76)
    at com.mycompany.client.login.Login_LoginUiBinderImpl.createAndBindUi(Login_LoginUiBinderImpl.java:30)
    at com.mycompany.client.login.Login_LoginUiBinderImpl.createAndBindUi(Login_LoginUiBinderImpl.java:1)
    at com.mycompany.client.login.Login.<init>(Login.java:50)
    at com.mycompany.client.login.SampleGwtTestCase.test01(SampleGwtTestCase.java:11)
    at com.mycompany.client.login.__SampleGwtTestCase_unitTestImpl.doRunTest(__SampleGwtTestCase_unitTestImpl.java:7)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:62)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runBare(GWTTestCase.java:188)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.__doRunTest(GWTTestCase.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner.runTest(GWTRunner.java:390)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner.doRunTest(GWTRunner.java:318)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner.access$9(GWTRunner.java:312)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner$TestBlockListener.onSuccess(GWTRunner.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner$InitialResponseListener.onSuccess(GWTRunner.java:63)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner$InitialResponseListener.onSuccess(GWTRunner.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:249)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Am I doing the test right?
Anything more required in configuration?
The test case works succesfully for classes without ui binders.
`GWT.create(...)` and native javascript codes also works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a configuration problem:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Remote test failed at 192.168.2.15 / Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19
> ```
>
> …
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null) @com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplTrident::isOrHasChildImpl(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Node;Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Node;)([JavaScript object(22), JavaScript object(26)]): null
> ```

You seem to have fixed the `user.agent` property to some value(s) that excludes `gecko1_8`, and `GWTTestCase` uses a Firefox 3 (Firefox 17 in GWT 2.6.0) emulation. If you don't care about Firefox (for whatever reason), or simply want to run the tests with an IE emulation, pass `-runStyle HtmlUnit:IE8` (valid values are FF2, FF3, IE6, IE7 and IE8 up until GWT 2.5.1, and FF17, IE8, IE9 and Chrome in GWT 2.6; you can pass multiple comma-separated values: `-runStyle HtmlUnit:IE6,IE8`) in the `gwt.args` system property (note: in Eclipse, setting this property in the *Arguments* tab overrides the options from the *GWT* tab, so you have to set them there too, e.g. `-Dgwt.args="-war www-test -runStyle HtmlUnit:IE8"`)

Comment: i tried it with `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />` in my gwt module. But still the same error.  
what is the Dgwt.args for firefox?