# Test GWT composite component with ui binder using GwtTestCase?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwttestcase

I'm writing a simple test class extending GwtTestCase for a component created with UiBinder, and running with `mvn gwt:test` fails as below.

The problem seems similar to: [How to test a gwt composite component with ui binder using GwtTestCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937576/how-to-test-a-gwt-composite-component-with-ui-binder-using-gwttestcase); other tests for components that are not created with UiBinder run fine with the current project configuration. 
The `user.agent` contains `gecko1_8`. I tried running from IntelliJ with `-Dgwt.args="-war www-test -runStyle HtmlUnit:IE8"` but I encountered another issue (`net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "__gwtDevModeHook:com.mypackage.MyEntryPoint.Junit"`).

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.Exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null) @com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplStandard::isOrHasChild(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Node;Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Node;)([JavaScript object(29), JavaScript object(30)]): null
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeBoolean(ModuleSpace.java:194)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeBoolean(JavaScriptHost.java:35)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplStandard.isOrHasChild(DOMImplStandard.java)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node$.isOrHasChild$(Node.java:280)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:220)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:190)
[INFO]  at com.mypackage.client.widgets.ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl$Widgets.build_f_HTMLPanel1(ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl.java:128)
[INFO]  at com.mypackage.client.widgets.ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl$Widgets.get_f_HTMLPanel1(ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl.java:112)
[INFO]  at com.mypackage.client.widgets.ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl$Widgets.access$0(ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl.java:111)
[INFO]  at com.mypackage.client.widgets.ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl.createAndBindUi(ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl.java:33)
[INFO]  at com.mypackage.client.widgets.ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl.createAndBindUi(ScreenHeader_ScreenHeaderUiBinderImpl.java:1)
[INFO]  at com.mypackage.client.widgets.ScreenHeader.<init>(ScreenHeader.java:38)
[INFO]  at com.mypackage.client.widgets.ScreenHeaderGwtTest.testConstructor(ScreenHeaderGwtTest.java:12)
[INFO]  at com.mypackage.client.widgets.__ScreenHeaderGwtTest_unitTestImpl.doRunTest(__ScreenHeaderGwtTest_unitTestImpl.java:7)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:62)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runBare(GWTTestCase.java:188)
```

Comment: Did you resolve this problem ?